# Roots of Unity form a Real Algebraic Group

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, roots-of-unity

Does the group $\mu_n$ of $n^{\mathrm{th}}$-roots of unity form an algebraic group over $\mathbb{R}$ for every $n$? If so, why?

I understand that $\mu_n$ forms an algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$, because it is given by the scheme $\mathrm{Spec}\, \mathbb{C}[x]/(x^n-1)$, but I don't see how to view it as an algebraic group over $\mathbb{R}$.

Perhaps this is trivial, because every scheme over $\mathbb{C}$ can be viewed as a scheme over $\mathbb{R}$, but I might be missing something here.

Comment: It's $\text{Spec } \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^n - 1)$, of course. In fact $\mu_n$ is defined as a group scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$.